# AWS ECS ServiceConnect: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when UI container tries to send request to backend microservice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have three services in the same namesapce on AWS Fargate: UI + two backend spring boot APIs.

All three services are configured to use ServiceNow, the backend are client-server and the UI is just client.

**Here is the port configuration for the backend services:**

Port Alias: fc-authentication-container-8080-tcp,
Discovery: authentication,
DNS: authentication.fc-test,
Port: 8080

Port Alias: fc-accounts-container-8081-tcp,
Discovery: accounts,
DNS: accounts.fc-test,
Port: 8081

However, when calls are made from the UI container I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

In the UI I am attempting to make a call to http://authentication.fc-test:8080 and http://accounts.fc-test:8080 but I get **POST http://authentication.fc-test:8080/api/v1/auth/authenticate net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

This is working when my services are running on localhost, but I can't get them to talk to eachother in AWS.

I made sure to create both the backend services first, so the UI should be able to see them on ServiceConnect, but for some reason it is not working.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Just realized my mistake: the UI is running from browser so needed to create application loadbalancers for the backend and update SGs accordingly.

All working now.

Comment: any chance you could elaborate? running into a similar issue myself